# Best way to store PHP form data before saving it to the database

Tags: php

I have a PHP form which, before to saving to MySQL database, will display all input entered by the user in a final confirmation page , this confirmation page will also let the user amend his answer. May I know what is the best way to store all these data prior to saving them in mysql? Should I write to a file, save them as session data, or in an array in memory which I then pass from page to page? Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Use sessions. the data is stored (fairly securely, relatively speaking) on the server in a file.

Comment: Simply store all data from form in the session.

Comment: This is what the sessions are for. You can also store the incomplete data in the database in a separate table and move it into the final table after the user reviews and confirms it.

Comment: Using hidden form fields is also an option. You can just re-validate the data before storing it, no need for sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to show the data from $_POST array at the page -- to allow user to check it.
And in the same time I rendered a form with the same data but putted in  fields, just below formatted message.
It allowed user to see how his data will looks like and to edit it in place if necessary, or just to submit it if everything is ok, or to use browser's autocomplete functionality when clicking  buttons.

```html
You inputed: <strong><?=$_POST['name']?></strong>
<h3>Please confirm if everything is ok:</h3>
<form action="/step2">
<input type="text" value="<?=$_POST['name']?>" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

BUt if the data is registration form or callback form, then you'll probably need to save even incomplete forms, especially phone number.
In that case I like using ajax-requests to save all fields one by one and to store them in the database. If it's really impossible to use exists step by step forms providers.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't using sessions be better than super globals as I can link the user inputs to a specific user? Saving to database is a gd idea but I'm just concerned abt the speed as I most probably wld have to move them to another table after user has confirmed. There are a hundred over field tat needs to be filled

Comment: what is a difference for you to use superglobal $_SESSION  or superglobal $_POST ?
Saving to DB -- yes, it really consumes resources. It's why I would like to have it only for email and phone fields. For that fields it's worth of it since I see 1/50 incomplete forms drops.

Answer (score 0):

Use super global variables cookies or sessions to store information to access the data after switching from one file to another.